How to create forum post using Javacord?
I have a function:
this.api.addModalSubmitListener(event -> {
            String modalId = event.getModalInteraction().getCustomId();

            switch (modalId) {
                case "send_app_modal":

                    String playerNick = event.getModalInteraction().getTextInputValueByCustomId("nick").orElse(null);
                    String about = event.getModalInteraction().getTextInputValueByCustomId("nick").orElse(null);

                    if (playerNick == null || about == null) {
                        event.getInteraction().createImmediateResponder()
                                .setFlags(MessageFlag.EPHEMERAL)
                                .setContent(SkylandWhitelist.rejectEmoji + " ...")
                                .respond();
                        return;
                    }

                    Server guild = event.getInteraction().getServer().get();

                    if (guild.getId() != SkylandWhitelist.DISCORD_GUILD_ID) return;

                    ServerForumChannel forumChannel = guild.getForumChannelById(1264885600738349107L).orElse(null);

                    if (forumChannel == null) {
                        event.getInteraction().createImmediateResponder()
                                .setFlags(MessageFlag.EPHEMERAL)
                                .setContent(SkylandWhitelist.rejectEmoji + " ...")
                                .respond();
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    break;
            }

        });

After checking forumChannel on null I need to create a new post in the forum, but in ServerForumChannel class I did not find the method. How do you release it?
I tried to look for a solution in the official documentation, looking through all the class methods, and asked for help from chatgpt, but found no answer anywhere.
